# how to check user's folder permissions in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

Is there a way to check if a particular windows user has access to a specific directory on a network share?

Or is there a way to capture the Windows "Access denied" error that displays when a user clicks a directory they don't have access to?

Thanks in Advance for any info anyone can share on this.

Answer (score 0):

If your asp classic code is trying to write or modify a file within a folder that the IIS user account does not have access to it will produce a [500 page error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525983.aspx).

You can setup a Custom Error Page to capture 500 errors. Once captured you can display a friendly error, log for action, etc